# jQuery/JS Input verification

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my simple form. I want to validate both inputs if it has some value inserted and that value is not a spaces. How can I achieve such functionality before request gets submitted to server side? Thanks a lot!

```
<form:form method="post" action ="${addQueryOverride}">
                    <label>Enter query string and product list ID: </label>
                    <input maxlength="30" class="text span-1" name="queryOverride" id="queryOverrideId"/>
                    <input onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="30" class="text span-1" name="productList" id="productListId"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add">
                </form:form>
```

Comment: you may trim the inputs val and check if value is not equal to Empty string

Comment: use `$('#productListId').val()` and validate

Comment: But how do I do that on button click? How I prevent execution forward if invalid input is detected? THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() { // when page load
  $("form").on("submit",function(e) {
    if ($.trim($("#queryOverrideId").val()) == "") {
      alert("Please enter query");
      $("#queryOverrideId").focus();
      return false;
    }
    var id = $("#productListId").val();
    if ($.trim(id) == "" || isNaN(id)) {
      alert("Please enter product list");
      $("#productListId").focus();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On submit, iterate over each of the fields and run a check:

```
$("form input:text").each(function() {
    var isValid = this.value.length > 0 && this.value.indexOf(" ") == -1;
    return isValid; //if true, go to next element, if false, break each loop
});
```